# How to identify if code runs inside the webservice?

Tags: .net, dll, service, web

I have a WCF service contract implementation which can be either used as a plain dll or as a web service. Is there any way to identify (from within its code) how is it used.
More specifically, I need to throw different exceptions in those cases.

Thank you

Comment: Need some more information. Do you have sample code, if this is a closed source component, do you have sample client code?

Comment: Could you use the OperationContext class to find out the IP address of machine calling the WCF service and see if it's the address of your web server?

Comment: Well, its simple. I have a  public class Service : IService{}, where IService is defined as ServiceContract. Service can be exposed through endpoints in a webservice, or just accessed by referencing the dll from an application.

Comment: Does the DLL itself also contain the WCF hosting code OR is the DLL just loaded by a WCF host in the case it is exposed as a WebService ? What is the host in this case (IIS...) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fair enough. In that case you could check various contexts in the library.

WCF

```
bool isWcf = OperationContext.Current != null;
```

Web

```
bool isWeb = System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null;
```

Comment: That might be the answer, I'll get back after trying it out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure of your specific requirements, but it seems like *plain dll* is a standard business logic library. Based on my experience, I'd suggest leaving the business logic as implementation agnostic as possible (within reason, of course) as you'll likely be handling the exceptions differently anyway. By throwing different exceptions based on the implementation, you'll be mixing the responsiblities of the business logic with those of the implementor.

My suggestion would be to throw a common set of exceptions from the business logic library, and catch/handle them differently for each implementation. E.g. a console application may just ask for the input again, where as a WCF application may throw a fault exception.

Take the following code as example:

```
// Simple business logic that throws common exceptions
namespace BusinessLogicLibrary
{
    public class Math
    {
        public static int Divide(int dividend, int divisor)
        {
            if (divisor == 0)
                throw new DivideByZeroException();

            return dividend / divisor;
        }
    }
}

// WCF calls to business logic and handles the exception differently
namespace WcfProject
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int Divide(int dividend, int divisor);
    }

    public class Service : IService
    {
        public int Divide(int dividend, int divisor)
        {
            try
            {
                return BusinessLogicLibrary.Math.Divide(dividend, divisor);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FaultException(
                    new FaultReason(ex.Message),
                    new FaultCode("Division Error"));
            }
        }
    }
}

// Console application calls library directly and handles the exception differently
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ShowDivide();
        }

        static void ShowDivide()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the dividend: ");
                int dividend = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the divisor: ");
                int divisor = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                int result = BusinessLogicLibrary.Math.Divide(dividend, divisor);
                Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
            }
            catch (DivideByZeroException)
            {
                // error occurred but we can ask the user again
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot divide by zero. Please retry.");
                ShowDivide();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, that is a common approach, but unfortunately is not an option in this current case.